# How do I make my c# Discord bot give someone a specific nickname after they react with a reaction for that nickname

Tags: c#, bots, discord.net

the title says it all but I do want my bot to give someone a **nickname** when they react with a certain reaction example: :ok_hand: gives them let's say an [AFK] nickname, and then maybe :thumbsdown: removes that nickname.

Comment: well you gotta handle user actions first then. like some switch cases.

Comment: @Halilİbrahim that's pretty confusing for me (I'm new to C# and Discord.net)

Comment: well there should be a library about user actions. just google about it. or check out documentation for Discord developer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `DiscordSocketClient` there is a `ReactionAdded` event, you can subscribe to that. Then I would suggest checking the reaction name first if it matches either ok_hand or thumbsdown, after that. Then download the message since it might no longer be cached: `var msg = await arg1.DownloadAsync();`. Then it is totally up to you, like only allow it in certain channels, after that check if the content matches. After that get the role from your Guild and add/remove it to the user.